# Constraints on Type Parameter only elements which occur in an array of types

Tags: c#, generics

I have this code:

```
 Type[] typList = GetAllTypesFromAssembly(Assembly.LoadFile("aaaa.dddd.dll"));
```

And this statement, which matches if my desired type will be in that list:

```
typeList.Contains(typeof(T));
```

Now I want change the constraints on my type parameter to something like this:

```
public byte[] resultA<T>(string some, T myCustomGenericParameter) : where typeList.Contains(typeof(T));
```

How to do it correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - because type constraints are designed to be verifiable by the *compiler*, whereas clearly `typeList.Contains(typeof(T))` is only checkable at execution time.

The simplest approach is probably just to validate it as a precondition of the method. It won't give you any compile-time protection, but at least you can be confident for the rest of the method.

Comment: hi, thank you, but what do you exactly mean with " validate it as a precondition of the method. ", can you give me an example ?

Comment: @zhuuuk: I mean you add a check at the start of the method, and throw an exception if the type argument is inappropriate.